# Where can I find a tehillim that is transliterated? (meaning the hebrew is translated on top or on bottom of the page)

Tags: translation, tehilim-psalms, transliteration

I'm searching for something with a big font and that is easy on the eyes.

Comment: "Transliterated" does not usually mean "translated on top or on bottom of the page".

Answer (score 3):

A transliterated tehillim looks like the following:

[Artscroll Transliterated Tehillim](https://www.eichlers.com/transliterated-linear-tehillim-psalms-seif-edition-artscroll-pocket-size-hardcover.html)

[image]

In actuality it seems as though you are looking for something more like this:

[Artscroll Interlinear Tehillim](https://www.eichlers.com/interlinear-tehillim-psalms-full-size-hardcover.html)

[image]